# How can I make a cell make a percentage based on how much more of "✅" there is in total?

Tags: checkbox, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, percentage, counting

Basically, I have a system showing checkmarks and Xmarks. I want to have a percentage below the cells saying how much ✅ there is, out of the total amount of cells available.

[image: Here is a picture for visuals:]

So as you can see, I have items on the left, and the ❌ is a item that...I guess we can say, hasn't been touched. But the ✅s mean the item has been touched. So at the bottom of the cells, I want a percentage to say how many ✅s out of the total amount of items. I also want this cell with the percentage to update with a new percentage every time I replace ❌ with ✅.

So if there was 9 ✅s, out of the 19 total items, it would be 47.37%% (right? I'm bad at math idk).

But when I replace the next X with a ✅, then it's 10 ✅s out of a total 19 items, so the percentage would **automatically** update to 52.63%.

How do I go about this? Is there a formula I can use?

Comment: Divide COUNTIF by the COUNT?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

logic is:

> **( Part / Total ) * 100 = Percentage**

```
=COUNTIF(B1:B19; TRUE)/COUNTA(B1:B19)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I noticed that worked when placing own Checkboxes, my original idea was to have the ✅ and ❌, which are not checkboxes. Is there anyway to do this formula for the text marks?

Comment: instead of TRUE type in your checked checkbox in quotes like: "✅"

Comment: That worked thanks, now is there a way to make another cell have a percentage saying how many ❌s were changed to a ✅ every 12 hours? (**"5 items touched last 12 hours"**) 

Also, about the spreadsheet sharing, I'm very self-cautious about it, and I'm only sharing it to a few other people, sorry about that. But your answers have still been very helpful.

Comment: for that you will need a script which will log events in a time frame (last 12h) and output report of changes. regular formulae are not capable to solve this